# Почему вываливается ошибка Class 'sergalas\header\Menus' not found?

Tags: php, yii2

Пытаюсь написать свой виджет который хотел бы поместить в папку `vendor/sergalas/header`

**Вот код:**

```
<?php
namespace sergalas\header;

use yii\base\Widget;
use common\models\Category;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

class Menus extends Widget {
    public $menu;
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $cat=Category::find()->where('tags=0')->all();
        $this->menu=ArrayHelper::toArray($cat,[
            'common\models\Category' => [
                'id',
                'name_category',

            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function run()
    {
        return 'Hello';
    }
}
```

Объясните пожалуйста где и в чем ошибка и как её исправить. Или хотя бы где искать ответ?

Comment: Папку `vendor` не стоит вообще трогать. Она ведь управляется Composer'ом. Посмотрите [документацию](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/structure-widgets.md) и сделайте по примеру.

Comment: А файл, в который помещаете класс, как называется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Папка `vendor` относится к `composer` и полностью им управляется. Для того, чтобы ваш код появился в этой папке, надо добавить ваш пакет на packagist.org. Это делается добавлением файла `composer.json` в корень вашего проекта на гитхабе.

В yii2 виджеты обычно находятся в папке `components`, по крайней мере так советует [документация](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-widgets.html#creating-widgets).